List of districts of Germany
I am working on a system where I need shapefiles for districts in Germany.
However, there is a lot of confusion around the exact number of districts.
Wikipedia entry says there are 401 districts - which seems to be the official number.
However, there are three exceptions: Aachen, Göttingen and Hanover. These three are listed twice. This takes the total count to 403. But if we remove these three, then there are only 400, but the official number is 401.
How can I get these?

There a 294 "Landkreise" (districts), and "106 kreisfreie Städte" (district-free cities)(https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landkreis).

There are more 'duplicates' beside those 3, but these are all separate districts, i.e. Rural and Urban

Thanks Erik. Strangely, the english version says 107 urban districts - probably that's where the confusion is

You find the answer here:

Gegenüber dem Zukunftsatlas 2019 gibt es eine kreisfreie Stadt
weniger: Die Stadt Eisenach gehört seit 2021 zum Wartburgkreis.
https://www.prognos.com/de/zukunftsatlas

Meaning: to town of Eisenach is no longer a district, since July 1st 2021 it is part of Wartburgkreis. So the number used to be 401, now it is 400.

The city Eisenach left the district in 1998 and became a district-free
city and was incorporated into the district again on 1 July 2021.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wartburgkreis


Thanks for this. The system we are developing is highly dependent on the correctness of the district boundaries. One question: is there a possibility of some rural districts getting merged into urban ones in future? If so, we'd better combine rural and urbans right from the start?

You must address this question to the german authorities. There is always a possibility of districts, cities, whole countries splitting up, merging etc. How would you want to forecast this? And even if you knew: would take the data of 2025? Or 2030? Or 2040? I think it depends only on your task and the problem in question what kind of data you want to have, no one can take this decision for you. In the case here: you need one dataset for the period before July 1st 2021 and another one for the period from then on.

Thanks, that makes sense. We are thinking of combining the polygons of rural and urban districts - that should keep us well prepared for any future rejig.

You could use the OSM Overpass API to get municipal boundaries
